# Login to google - Sheet API

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I have an application for the localhost that downloads data from google sheet - it works as it should ...
I moved it to an external server on mikrohost.pl - I made a new user, set it up like the previous account ...
and trying to log in crashes me:
The authorization state [state=HA-SE26O0CYMZJF73RILN8P4H1TQAD9KVU5WBGX] of this page is either invalid or has already been consumed.

my config.php file:

```
<?php
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'class-db.php';

define('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID', 'GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com');
define('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET', 'wygenerowanyWconsoliGoogle');
 
$config = [
    'callback' => 'http://adres/do/callback.php',
    'keys'     => [
        'id' => GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        'secret' => GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
    ],
    'scope'    => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
    'authorize_url_parameters' => [
        'approval_prompt' => 'force', // to pass only when you need to acquire a new refresh token.
        'access_type' => 'offline'
    ]
];
 
$adapter = new Hybridauth\Provider\Google( $config );
?>
```

My callback.php

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
 
try {
    $adapter->authenticate();
    $token = $adapter->getAccessToken();
    $db = new DB();
    if($db->is_table_empty()) {
        $db->update_access_token(json_encode($token));
        echo "Access token inserted successfully.";
    }
}
catch( Exception $e ){
    echo $e->getMessage() ;
}
```

I generated a new OAuth dataset for the google user, where I am logged in to localhost app, but I still get the same error - the application works on localhost. I don't know what's wrong
I have PHP v7.4.21

Comment: Can be an issue with session management. You can try reading here https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/issues/1015

Please let me know if existing comments there still does not solve your problem.

Comment: I try open in Edge - and it work... (normal I use google chrome)